# PHP variable within pre set string

Tags: php, string

Say I do this:

```
$string = 'some string with a {$var}';

// Set var after
$var = 'variable'

// String with just set var
$newString = 'Here is my string: ' . $string;
echo $newString;
```

How would I make it output:

```
Here is my string: some string with a variable
```

I could do it with str_replace but I was wondering if there was an easier way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on your example I think [`sprintf()`](http://www.php.net/sprintf) would work for you:

```
$string = 'some string with a %s';
$var = 'variable';
$newString = sprintf($string, $var);
```

Comment: +1, one can also use [printf()](http://php.net/printf) in this case. `printf()` will directly output the string instead of returning it.